# Migrating Mail.app rules from 10.6 to 10.8

Tags: mail.app, macos, mail-rules

I want to move my Mail.app filtering rules from my old 10.6 machine to a fresh 10.8 install. I've seen people talking about moving these by copying over  MessageRules.plist, but I haven't seen anyone address whether these are compatible between 10.6 and 10.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I copied all of the user-created `<dict>...</dict>` items from my old `MessageRules.plist` and added them to:

```
~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/UnsyncedRules.plist
```

When I launched Mail.app again, they were in my rules, but disabled. One click on each and they ran fine.

**Note**: Simply replacing the entire set of `<dict>...</dict>` items in `UnsyncedRules.plist` will not work. You must add them into the current set of items in order for it to work properly.

Comment: I also had to make various edits because the folder references needed to be changed to reflect new paths with V2.  It helped to make a dummy rules refiling to subfolders in each of my accounts, so that I could see how they should look.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who tried copying the MessageRules.plist file over from 10.6 to 10.8 and got nothing here's what I did to get them working.

Essentially copy all the rules via copy/paste from  MessageRules.plist (10.6) to SyncedRules.plist (10.8) - use a text editor to copy and paste everything from the `</array>` tags in the old file to the new one. Then restart Mail.

Longer version:
Copy MessageRules.plist from Users>User>Library>Mail> on your 10.6 machine to anywhere your 10.8 machine. Open up the file in a text editor and copy everything between the `<array></array>` Tags. Then paste it all in the file SyncedRules.plist on your 10.8 machine in Library>Mail>V2>MailData inbetween the`<array>` tags. Restart the Mail app and all the rules should show up in preferences section.

Mail will slowly even create the folders/mailboxes to store the messages in folders that don't exist but are pointed too in your rules that you imported.